# Wordpress: About callers and catches

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins

Before I start: The question is not about "how to save form data to database and show it on frontend". It's about "how to post, call and catch data in wordpress". Becouse in this freetime project I have to use Wordpress as the core of a webapp and this is my first time when I develop a WP plugin.

I have a custom post type. For example "books".
I have a "bookpage": Tolstoj - War and Peace.
At the bottom of this page there is a form where the reader can log this book as "read".
Form fields: "when I started", "when I ended", "rating".

I want to catch the logged in user, save this in the database, and then show the "read logs" above the form.

My questions:

- Is there any "wordpress method" for this type of task (I don't want to reinvent the wheel)
- How to catch the logged in user's ID and the requested URL's end? (for example my URL: www.myawesomesite.com/books/LJT001, than I want to get the LJT001 part)
- I will make the form without plugin (just simply with html). What to call with the `action` parameter and how to catch with my plugin (what will save to the database) if my plugin's  textdomain is `myawesomesitesite-readplugin`?

I don't have code snippets yet, becouse I don't know yet where to start.